# Easiest way to install pygtk on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, gtk, pip, homebrew

Ideally, I would like to install pygtk using pip or Homebrew. Neither one seems to be possible.

I am running Leopard.

Comment: You can download the whole package and install easily from [`here`](http://macpkg.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install pygtk yourself - at least because since some of its dependencies like dextras are not available through PyPI.

Answer (score 6):

I've archive some success running tryton which uses pygtk with Homebrew.

I've uninstalled anything installed before in Homebrew and installed again with:

```
brew install pygtk
```

I guess to do the trick is setting the PYTHONPATH as brew says end of install, I do my setup in ~/.bashrc file.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I hope it helps