# How to transfer pygobject3 for use with PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I have the same problem as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629270/how-do-i-properly-install-pygobject-osx?newreg=4b36028a191c42fab5159e80bd714525) but my copy of pygobject3 is installed in the following path:

`/usr/local/Cellar/pygobject3/3.36.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

How and where do I transfer it so PyCharm can see it?

PyCharm can't install it for some reason.