# How do I properly install PyGObjct on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos-high-sierra

I'm using Mac OS: High Sierra: 10.13.6, and my understanding of Terminal is very limited as I am an eager beginner.

Starting from the beginning of my attempt: I first attempted to use [`pip3`](https://pypi.org/project/PyGObject/) to install `PyGObject`. However, this failed with:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/Tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python3.7 /Users/Tyler/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/dd/9fgky8s10l569qd01qvwpvxh0000gn/T/tmp38e67qsx
       cwd: /private/var/folders/dd/9fgky8s10l569qd01qvwpvxh0000gn/T/pip-install-xhr95ubc/pygobject_0051309210034fd284903e60ab3ede2a
  Complete output (39 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/pygtkcompat
  "many other copying statements - though it was unnecessary so deleted (ME)"
  copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/gi/overrides
  running build_ext
  Requested 'libffi >= 3.0' but version of libffi is 2.1
  Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'libffi >= 3.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
Failed to build PyGObject
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

After this I discovered [`brew`](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). I run the code here and everything appears to be up to date:

```
tylers-macbook-pro:~ Tyler$ brew install pygobject3 gtk+3
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: pygobject3 3.38.0_1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.38.0_1, run `brew reinstall pygobject3`
Warning: gtk+3 3.24.24 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.24.24, run `brew reinstall gtk+3`
```

I am still unable to import the `gi` module from terminal:

```
tylers-macbook-pro:~ Tyler$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 28 2020, 16:08:31) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> import gi 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
>>>
```

I have found that the packages installed by `HomeBrew` are at:

```
/Users/Tyler/Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

From my reading, I believe that the last post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629270/how-do-i-properly-install-pygobject-osx) could be the solution or part of it, however, my skill and understanding of my computer is stopping me from *"giving it a go"* as I may destroy something that I do not know how to put back together. I also acknowledge that I have an early 2011 MacBook pro that I have spiced up with an SSD and more RAM. However, Apple no longer allows me to update my computer much to my disappointment.

Comment: Just curious, does the same happen if you run `$ python3` instead of just `$ python`?

Comment: Hey @genbatro,
I tried what you suggested, however, I did not have any luck. I tried the following commands in terminal. I first typed "python3 + return" followed with "import gi + return". This resulted in an error message saying that the gi module could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried installing the dependencies as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705973

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I rage quit after troubleshooting with no luck. I followed the commands from the link you included. I get a "0" by using the echo $? command, which apparently suggested that everything is "well in the hood".
I tried following the instructions for <brew install node>, however, this failed with "Error: node: no bottle avaliable! "

Comment: <brew doctor> outputs "Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories." I have tried to fix this, however, I apparently was not able to resolve the issue ha ha.