# Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb

Tags: python, macos, gtk, homebrew, gtk3

I was tying to install `mitmproxy`

```
brew reinstall mitmproxy
```

> Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb!
>
> Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb!

Then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956985/how-to-install-pygtk-3-on-mac-os-x) answer and tried the following, but same results.

```
brew reinstall pygobject3  gtk+3
```

> Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb!
>
> Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb!
>
> Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb!
>
> Error: could not get runtime dependencies from /usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb!

File `/usr/local/opt/pygtk/.brew/pygtk.rb` is present and its content is:

```
class Pygtk < Formula
  desc "GTK+ bindings for Python"
  homepage "http://www.pygtk.org/"
  url "https://download.gnome.org/sources/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2"
  sha256 "cd1c1ea265bd63ff669e92a2d3c2a88eb26bcd9e5365e0f82c896e649f206912"
  revision 1

  option :universal

  depends_on "pkg-config" => :build
  depends_on "glib"
  depends_on "gtk+"
  depends_on "atk"
  depends_on "pygobject"
  depends_on "py2cairo"
  depends_on "libglade" => :optional

  def install
    ENV.append "CFLAGS", "-ObjC"
    ENV.universal_binary if build.universal?
    system "./configure", "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make", "install"

    # Fixing the pkgconfig file to find codegen, because it was moved from
    # pygtk to pygobject. But our pkgfiles point into the cellar and in the
    # pygtk-cellar there is no pygobject.
    inreplace lib/"pkgconfig/pygtk-2.0.pc", "codegendir=${datadir}/pygobject/2.0/codegen", "codegendir=#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/pygobject/2.0/codegen"
    inreplace bin/"pygtk-codegen-2.0", "exec_prefix=${prefix}", "exec_prefix=#{Formula["pygobject"].opt_prefix}"
  end

  test do
    (testpath/"codegen.def").write("(define-enum asdf)")
    system "#{bin}/pygtk-codegen-2.0", "codegen.def"
  end
end
```

```
brew doctor
```

> Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew
> maintainers with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use
> Homebrew for is working fine: please don't worry or file an issue;
> just ignore this. Thanks!
>
> Warning: Some installed formulae were deleted! You should find
> replacements for the following formulae:   dirmngr   gpg-agent
> heroku   mongodb   node@6   phantomjs   pygobject   pygtk   python@2
>
> Warning: You have the following deprecated, official taps tapped:
> Homebrew/homebrew-gui   Homebrew/homebrew-science
> Homebrew/homebrew-x11 Untap them with `brew untap`.
>
> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew
> directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to
> determine if software packages are installed, and which additional
> flags to use when compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed
> via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or
> Homebrew-provided script of the same name. We found the following
> "config" scripts:   /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python2-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python2.7-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.3-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.3m-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.4-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.4m-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.5-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.5m-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.6-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.6m-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.7-config
> /Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/shims/python3.7m-config
>
> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar. Leaving kegs unlinked
> can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
> fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:   dirmngr
> gpg-agent   node@6   opencv   python@2   python@3.8   youtube-dl
>
> Error: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mountain_lion

```
brew config
```

> HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.4.11 ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
> HEAD: 9ef993ab570ac6d4f2c4f88a96f2da8c3e71fa85 Last commit: 6 days ago
> Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core Core tap
>
> HEAD: 209e837530c0363e60ee3cd8cc493bfca37d411a Core tap last commit:
> 43 minutes ago Core tap branch: master HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
>
> HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
> HOMEBREW_DISPLAY:/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.faf9YzPVVH/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
>
> HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4 CPU: quad-core 64-bit ivybridge Homebrew Ruby:
> 2.6.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
> Clang: 10.0 build 1000 Git: 2.17.1 => /usr/local/bin/git Curl: 7.54.0
> => /usr/bin/curl Java: 1.8.0_121 macOS: 10.13.6-x86_64 CLT: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718 Xcode: 10.1 XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11

Comment: Can you paste `brew doctor` and `brew config` for troubleshooting? Thanks!

Comment: @chenrui updated with details that you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on brew doctor here you go:

```
brew uninstall pygtk pygobject
brew install pyk+3 pygobject3
brew install mitmproxy
```